# Add SSL binding to Azure custom domain

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Trying to add SSL binding for a custom domain, but keep getting the error message "Cannot enable SNI SSL for a hostname 'xxx.com' because current site mode does not allow it."

The app service plan is in the D1 (shared infrastructure) tier, and the SSL certificate is one that I (accidentally) purchased through azure.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#check-the-pricing-tier: "Custom SSL is not supported in the F1 or D1 tier."

Comment: I missed that, sneaky of them.

Comment: This sucks really... so much for the Azure cloud being the cheap alternative.

Comment: That's amazing. It's all nice and cheap until you need to do what every other functioning website does, which is to have a custom domain name and SSL, and suddenly it's $50/mo.

Comment: Custom domains and SSL are included in the B1 tier, which is considerably cheaper if it's Linux instead of Windows - about $13/mo vs $68/mo at the time of writing.

Comment: You have the *free* option to use Azure's Managed Certificate. In the App Service > TLS/SSL settings > Private Key Certificates (.pfx) select the right most option "Create App Service Managed Certificate.  You will need to add a txt and cname record in your DNS to prove you own the domain. Once this is created you can add it to the custom domain binding. It will use the azurewebsites.net cert and is all managed by Azure for free so you don't need to buy a cert and you never need to renew it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @user888734 for the tip. Switched my machine to B1 Linux and SSL worked (13$).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to use Azure App Certificate SSL w/out upgrade a shared resource account to a more expensive account that allows SSL config.

```
1. Download Azure App Certificate
2. Install Certificate to a local machine
3. Export the certificate from the local machine and add password protection to the export certificate
4. Open Azure -> Custom domains -> Add binding -> upload the pfx certificate and now you can type your password
```

Comment: It's asking for private key password while installing cert on the local machine. Do you know where I can find that from?

Comment: Leave it blank @CuriousDrive